# Getting 403 in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have sent the set-cookie, but in response, I'm getting values like setcookie :[array].

```
   response: {
        status: 403,
        statusText: 'Forbidden',
        headers: {
          server: 'nginx',
          date: 'Mon, 22 Aug 2022 17:13:36 GMT',
          'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'content-length': '40',
          connection: 'close',
          'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
          'x-request-id': '8de5f5a9-92e4-4165-9104-03b59a1d45ad',
          etag: 'W/"28-QvgnGTKO2Xab8i/l/pv6isQnqF0"',
          vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
          'set-cookie': [Array]
        },
```

Down below, I m sharing the code which I'm hitting the api .

```
app.js
 

     try {
        let data = req.body;
        const value = await axios.post(
          "https://example.com",
          data,
          {
            headers: {
              Cookie: `connect.sid=${result}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );
      
        res.status(200).send(value.data);
      } catch (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
```

Comment: So it's not Express returning a 403, but the Axios request? Or is the Axios request made against your Express server? If so, why is the response coming from an Nginx server?

Comment: Above code, I m using it for proxyApi to connect remoteApi and also it is working in postman

Comment: Are you sure that `result` is valid? What would cause your Express server to return a 403? Your question is missing a lot of context. Also, the reason `[Array]` is being shown is because you're using `console.log()`, which limits the depth at which it will output objects.